# How to select a remote folder as one drive folder?

Tags: onedrive

I want to use a folder on the server as target for one drive but when I try to select it, it tells me I can't create the folder in that location. It works if I select a local folder instead. I believe I have all permissions to write to the selected path.

Is there something I'm missing or is this possibility not supported? How can I "trick" one drive into using a folder on the server?